# How can I get an input field to appear in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run the following code:

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))

if num > 0:

    print("That's a positive number!")
```

[image]
The first time that I run it, I will get an input prompt underneath the code's cell asking me to "Enter a Number". The program will function as expected in JupyterLab, but only once. After I try to run the code again (or copy and paste it into a new cell), the "Enter a number" prompt will no longer appear, but a new input cell will appear instead:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't reproduce what you describe, as a workaround, and if you want to keep track of the input, you can do:

```
while num != -999:
    num=int(input("Enter a number (to finish use -999): "))

    if num>0:
        print(num)
```

You can use other number than -999 or you can also cast to int **in the `if` statement** and use some string to exit the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Jupyter widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!

You need some code like this in a cell to display a widget:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

numWidget = widgets.IntText(
    description='Enter a number:',
    disabled=False
)
```

You can get the value of the widget whenever you need it with:

```py
num = numWidget.value
```